# SQL Server: Windowing function error

Tags: sql-server

When I run the query below (from a temp table I created called #Temp_CallHistory), I get the error:
"The function 'ROW_NUMBER' may not have a window frame."

```
SELECT  RootCall_Id
    ,   CallID
    ,   CallCode
    ,   CreationDT
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RootCall_Id
                    ORDER BY CreationDT
                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS RankOfEvents
FROM #Temp_CallHistory;
```

However, if I run the same query without specifying "ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW", I do not get the error.

Does anyone have an idea why I'm getting this error when I specify "ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW"? Note that I also get the error when I explicitly specify the default "RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW".

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you expect the ROWS BETWEEN window to do for this query? I'm having a hard time figuring out the point of partitioning by the ID, ordering by the date, and within that, applying a window. Running row numbers? How would that work? Can you show sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `ROW_NUMBER` is a ranking function and does not accept the `RANGE`/`ROWS` argument. You can read more about this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/ms189461.aspx) in the General Remarks section.

Comment: And more specifically, window framing using RANGE/ROWS doesn't really make sense, since a rank or row number has to consider all rows (or all rows in the group, when using partition by) anyway. How would it apply row numbers to the rows outside of the window frame but within the same group?